# Can I conditionally call a library based on HTML element?

Tags: 8, theming

I would like to use [DataTables.js](https://datatables.net/) for tables created by content editors in the main body field of a content type. I already have the library installed in my libraries.yml.

I had an idea that I could avoid calling the library globally, but instead have it only be called on a page that has an HTML `<table>` element rendered.

That idea came from drupal.org documentation [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module#type), which offers up this code example for the `hook_element_info_alter()` function:

```
function fluffy_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  if (isset($types['table'])) {
    $types['table']['#attached']['library'][] = 'fluffiness/fancy_table';
  }
}
```

However when I checked into the theme.api, I saw this code is intended for people making modules and indeed the documentation section I saw it in was for modules.

Can I use this same or similar bit of code in my **theme_name.theme** file to apply to all nodes? Is there something else I should do instead?

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Comment: Correct, that is only for element theming.

Comment: Correct, in that I can use it to theme the table element (and all its rows inside)?

Comment: No, element in this case does not mean basic HTML tag, it refers to form elements. There is no hook that will parse a body field and pick up on table tags.

Comment: I would either attach the library to node types that have a body field, or look at the body field content and regex for '<table' - if there is a match, attach the library.

Comment: @Kevin, I really appreciate your input, thanks. I don't even begin to know how to do what you said. Can you point me to any documentation or examples I could use to start understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_element_info_alter` won't suit in this situation because you are trying to do something based on the value of a body field, which is just 'text' as far as Drupal is concerned. `Element` in the Drupal world is different. But here is an approach to your problem.

You can implement `hook_preprocess_node` and check if the body field value contains `<table` - and if there is a hit, then attach the library:

```
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode;

function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $match = Unicode::strpos($node->field_body->value, '<table');

  if ($node->field_body->value && $match !== FALSE) {
    // next line is just an example
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/libraryname';
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/datatables';
  }
}
```

This will only attach the library to a node being rendered IF the node body field has a value, and within it, there is a match for an opening table tag.

The `use` statement should go at the top of your *mytheme.theme* file.

`strpos` has a caveat:

> Note that a return value of 0 is not the same as FALSE.

So if you plan on using this a little more elsewhere, take note.

Comment: To @Kevin and all the folks like him who take the time to craft an answer like this, I really want to express my gratitude. Not only did Kevin's answer work great for me but it's also building my understanding of pre-processing. This answer keeps on giving because it's thorough in explaining some opaque concepts and I'm growing as a developer. Thanks again for investing your time in the community.

Comment: No problem. Preprocess hooks are a good way to do things like this.